# Is white space considered a token in C like languages?

Tags: c, parsing, whitespace

Is white space considered a type of token in C like languages (especially interested in C specifically)? The Reference Manual in K&R seemed a little vague on this.

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6sb2c6b.aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, white space would not be considered a token. From http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.4.html (the draft standard text, unfortunately the actual standards cost money and have no open link):

> ```
> token:
>                 keyword
>                 identifier
>                 constant
>                 string-literal
>                 punctuator
>
> preprocessing-token:
>                 header-name
>                 identifier
>                 pp-number
>                 character-constant
>                 string-literal
>                 punctuator
>                 each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above
> ```

[GCC does not consider white space tokens](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html):

> White space separates tokens; it is not itself a token of any kind.
>   Tokens do not have to be separated by white space, but it is often
>   necessary to avoid ambiguities.

nor does [Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9a023cx.aspx):

> Tokens are delimited (bounded) by white-space characters and by other
>   tokens, such as operators and punctuation. When parsing code, the C
>   compiler ignores white-space characters unless you use them as
>   separators or as components of character constants or string literals.

K&R **A2.1 Tokens** may be ambiguous, but is in line with these texts:

> There are six classes of tokens: identifiers, keywords, constants,
>   string literals, operators, and other separators.  Blanks, horizontal
>   and vertical tabs, newlines formfeeds, and comments as described below
>   (collectively, "white space") are ignored except as they separate
>   tokens.